# StaticInjector vs ReflectiveInjector in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-di

Angular 5.x will include new `StaticInjector` as mentioned [in this tweet](https://twitter.com/PascalPrecht/status/894837982871605248). I have two questions:

- How is it different from existing ReflectiveInjector?
- Will it break any of my existing code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, there's a great article [Angular introduces StaticInjector. Should you care?](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-introduces-staticinjector-should-you-care-4e059eca030c) that explains the difference in details.

> How is it different from existing ReflectiveInjector?

#### ReflectiveInjector

Relies on reflection capabilities provided by `Reflect` library to extract the implicit dependencies for a provider, hence the name `Reflective`:

```
class B {}
class A {
  constructor(@Inject(B) b) { } <----- `B` is implicit dependency
}

const i = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([A, B]);
```

The `@Inject` decorator defines the metadata specifying implicit dependencies and `ReflectiveInjector` uses this metadata.

#### StaticInjector

Doesn't use reflective capabilities and requires to specify the dependencies explicitly:

```
class B {}
class A { constructor(b) {} }
const i = Injector.create([{provide: A, useClass: A, deps: [B]]};
const a = i.get(A);
```

> Will it break any of my existing code?
>   The change will only affect providers supplied to platform and compiler providers. So if you provided them like this:

```
class B1 {}
class A1 { constructor(@Inject(B1) b) {} }

class B2 {}
class A2 { constructor(@Inject(B2) b) {} }
bootstrapModule(AppModule, {providers: [A1, B1]}).platformBrowserDynamic([A2, B2])
```

You should now change that to:

```
class B1 {}
class A1 { constructor(b) {} }

class B2 {}
class A2 { constructor(b) {} }

platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: A1, useClass: A1, deps: [B1] }, B1])
.bootstrapModule(AppModule, { providers: [ {provide: A2, useClass: A2, deps: [B2]}, B2 ] })
```

The `ReflectiveInjector` is still marked as stable so you can probably continue using it. But there's a great probability that it will be removed in the future. I suggest you start using `StaticInjector` as soon as it's available.

Comment: Let's go one step back. why would I want to use `bootstrapModule(AppModule, { providers: [...` & `platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide:` at first place ? can u please supply sample codes ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, if you want to define custom providers at the platform level. This is used mostly by other platforms like webworker and universal

Comment: the link is broken